# Error 1055, Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to see how many customers who came directly (which is where marketing medium would be blank) to the site before making a purchase. Session id is when they go onto the site and the session has been started. Visitor id is their unique identifier.

```
Select
  session_id,
  purchase_time
FROM orders
 where marketing_medium is NULL
 Group by visitor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to even use `GROUP BY` here, at least not based on the requirements you did tell us.  Instead, maybe you need `ORDER BY visitor_id`:

```
SELECT
    visitor_id,
    session_id,
    purchase_time
FROM orders
WHERE
    marketing_medium IS NULL
ORDER BY
    visitor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of customers, then you only need `COUNT()` without `GROUP BY`:

```
select count(visitor_id) counter
from orders
where marketing_medium is null
```

If you want to count each distinct customer only once even if he made many purchases, use `DISTINCT`:

```
select count(distinct visitor_id) counter
from orders
where marketing_medium is null
```